# Counting nodes in BST

Tags: java, stack-overflow, binary-search-tree

I keep getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError` at this line:

```
count += countNodes(current.leftChild);
```

when I try to count the total number of the nodes in BST. Could somebody please tell me why I'm getting that error? Thanks in advance!

```
public int countNodes(Node node){
        if(root == null){
            System.out.println("The tree is empty!");
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            int count = 1;
            Node current = root;
            while(current.leftChild != null){
                count += countNodes(current.leftChild);
            }
            while(current.rightChild != null){
                count += countNodes(current.rightChild);
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didnt change the current and you run while on it... maybe you want if and not while. you wrote strange recursion. try not use the while

Comment: `Node current = root;` maybe issue too...

Comment: Do you still have a problem?

Comment: @Alon, I'd appreciate if you could help me how to count the number of nodes in BST

Comment: @John did you try my answer?

Comment: @Alon, I did. But I dont see much difference between your code and mine

Comment: @John I changed the while to if and the return -1 to 0.

Comment: @Alon, still gives `java.lang.StackOverflowError` in line `count += countNodes(current.leftChild);`

Comment: @John you sure that the child of the leaves of the tree is null?
And look at my code.. Copy all the code.. I changed also the title..

Comment: @Alon, it worked, sorry! Thank you very much!

Comment: @John When you use while then you you run the function countNodes(current.rightChild); infinit time cause you dont change the current so current.rightChild will not be null.And if you can please upvote my answer..

Comment: @John  can please upvote my answer cause it -1.. thanks!

Comment: @Alon, I already upvoted it days ago, before it was `-2`, I think. OR it says "Your vote is locked is unless this answer is edited". Try to edit smth and I'll upvote if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this I think it should work

```
public int countNodes(Node root){
    if(root == null){
        System.out.println("The tree is empty!");
        return 0;
    } 
    else{
        Node current = root;
        int count = 0 
        if(current.leftChild != null){
            count +=  countNodes(current.leftChild)+1;
        }
        if(current.rightChild != null){
            count += countNodes(current.rightChild)+1;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

You go in recursion from the root to the leaves. Look at your code you go with while loop. The problem that in this recursion you go to the depth with the recursion and not with the while loop.

you take the result from the operation of the left tree and add it to the operation on the right.
The stopping condition of the recursion is when the root dont have childs.

When

```
  current.rightChild == null && current.leftChild == null
```

Maybe I confused with the init of count. check it..

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just realized I posted that response like 1 minute after you posted your answer. I bet you were still editing it to add an explanation. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your original code.

The first is that you use `while` statements when looking at the left and right subtrees. Since you never change the value of `current`, these loops will run forever.

The second problem is that you take a parameter called `node`, but never use it. Instead, within the method body, you refer to another variable `root`. This is what is causing your StackOverflowError.

Changing the `while`s to `if`s should help with the infinite looping, and renaming some variables so that you use the value of parameter to the function should fix the stack overflow problem.

As a side note, you may want to return zero when the node is null instead of -1. That way, you can make recursive calls without having to check the null-ness of the children, and, more importantly, when the tree has zero nodes in it, the function says so. Right now, a tree with zero nodes looks like it has -1 nodes.

Comment: I see that my answer has been downvoted, and I apologize if I gave a poor answer. However, it would be more helpful for me if I could be told why my answer is unsatisfactory so that I may improve in the future.

Answer (score 0):

//^_^

```
public int getCount(){
    return getCount(root);
}

public int getCount(BSTNode<T> p){
    if(p == null){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        int count = 1;
        BSTNode<T> current = p;
        while(current.left != null){
            count += getCount(current.left);
        }
        while(current.right != null){
            count += getCount(current.right);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add info what you are trying to suggest in your solution

Comment: but my sol is true because my sol is calc the root with tree In method int getCount()